# How do I pass a range as a parameter in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, range

In Delphi, I can define a range of characters or integers as demonstrated below:

```
var
  a,i: integer;
  b: char;
  intrange: 1..9;
  charrange: 'α' .. 'ζ';

begin

  for a := low(IntRange) to high(IntRange) do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Integer Range Iteration = ' + intToStr(a) ) ;
  end;

  i:=0;
  for b := low(charrange) to high(charrange) do
  begin
    i := i + 1;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Character Range Iteration = ' + intToStr(i) + ',   value = ' + b +'  ord '+ inttostr(ord(b))) ;
  end;
end;
```

How can I pass a range as a parameter to a function?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. The best you can do is pass the lower and upper bounds or the set of all the values in the range.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [subrange types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Subrange_Types):

```
type
  TCharrange = 'α' .. 'ζ';

procedure MyFunction(Char: TCharrange);
```

Now you can do

```
MyFunction('γ');
```

whereas

```
MyFunction('a');
```

won't work.

Comment: So what 'type' is a range, if it's defined locally?

Comment: Subrange types are described officially here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Subrange_Types. In this case, it is a "restricted" `char` type.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question you want to pass a range rather than a character that is within some specified range. If that is a correct understanding then you would need to pass two parameters (min and max) or perhaps wrap them up in a record.

Comment: +1. I also considered this interpretation of the question, but chose to answer the other interpretation since that is much more "answer-friendly". So +1 for completeness.

Comment: Probably the simplest and most practical method, but I was curious as to whether I could pass the actual range var itself.

Comment: @HMcG I don't know what you mean by a range var. The *variable* is a single value within the defined *range*. The range is a type and the variable is an value of that type. Since the range type is known at compile time it would be odd to pass it as a parameter. Could you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hefferman, I was suffering from a misunderstanding of how the range was being defined. Not really trying to accomplish a particular task, just trying to get a better understanding of the language features and how they can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You can try sets in certain cases, for example:

```
type
  TMyRange = 1..5;
  TMyRangeSet = Set of TMyRange;

procedure A(const V: TMyRangeSet);
var X : TMyRange;
begin
  for X := Low(TMyRange) to High(TMyRange) do
    if X in V then { included } 
end;

begin
  A([3..4]);
end.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with a Unicode range - ['a'..'g'] will work but ['α' .. 'ζ'] will not. Which is a pity as it is a nice syntax.

Comment: Helped me for a different question - How to pass a set as a parameter or have as a result type in a function

Answer (score 3):

I beleive you'd need to define it as a type first, something like:

```
type
  TMyRange = 1..2;
```

then:

```
function Whatver(Range: TMyRange): Boolean;
begin

end;
```

Comment: Thankyou, Andreas Rejbrand just pipped you to the post. I am always amazed at how quickly Stackoverflow can answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

I am rather new to generics, but I think that this might be a rather neat solution to the second interpretation (the David Heffernan interpretation) of your problem.

```
type
  TRange<T> = record
    MinVal: T;
    MaxVal: T;
    constructor Create(AMinVal, AMaxVal: T);
  end;

  TCharrange = TRange<Char>;
  // TIntrange = TRange<Integer>;
  // etc.

constructor TRange<T>.Create(AMinVal, AMaxVal: T);
begin
  MinVal := AMinVal;
  MaxVal := AMaxVal;
end;
```

Now you can do

```
procedure MyFunction(Char: TCharrange);
begin
  ShowMessage(Char.MinVal);
  ShowMessage(Char.MaxVal);      
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TCharrange;
begin
  r.Create('a', 'c');
  MyFunction(r);
end;
```